# Problema com chamada assíncrona

Tags: node.js, express.js

Boa noite pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou com uma situação chata e não sei como resolver...

É o seguinte, estou desenvolvendo uma API para fazer uma ponte entre os dados que estão em um banco de dados e um sistema de terceiro, ou seja, minha API consulta os dados do meu banco de dados e retorna um array de objetos, a cada objeto desse array é um POST que preciso fazer no sistema.

Atualmente consulto e faço um map com Promise.All.. Faço a iteração pra cada objeto do array e mando um POST para o outro sistema, só que no momento que faz o POST ele não espera o retorno do sistema do meu cliente e já considera como se tivesse tido sucesso.

Não consigo saber se deu certo ou errado a requisição por que ele já pula para a próxima iteração, se eu tento retornar o response pro return (Arquivo que realiza o POST) ele considera como erro.

Vou deixar o código abaixo.

Agradeço muito desde já pessoal,

Valeu!

```
1. Arquivo da Iteração

Promise.all(integracoes.map(async int => {
  return await webserviceController.enviaRequisicao(
      int.INT_CH_TIPO_OPERACAO,
      int.INT_ST_TIPO_DOC,
      int
    );
})).then(response => {
  return res
  .status(200)
  .json({ Mensagem: 'Registros integrados com sucesso' });
}).catch(reject => {
  return res.status(400).json({
    message: 'Erro na execução do método',
    error: reject
  });
});

2. Arquivo do envio dos objetos do array

async criaDocumento(request) {
  try {
    const { ANEXOS: anexos, ...rest } = request;

    const [requestJSONDocument, fieldsDocument] = removeFields(rest, 'D');

    const response = await api.post('/NotasFiscais', requestJSONDocument, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });

    const { id } = response.data;

    const responseJSON = { CUS_IN_IDWS: id , ...fields };

    return responseJSON;

  } catch (error) {
    throw 'Erro ao tentar integrar a Nota Fiscal.';
  }
}
```

Comment: Na linha 9 esse 'response' está sendo usado? Parece que você criou ela só que está passando como 'res'

Comment: No caso eu não estou utilizando, teria que tratar nesse caso será? Só que quando eu eu tento passar pro result a variável responseJSON JSON pro return da erro =/ Será se não é possível utilizar async com o map?

Comment: tenta dar um console.log nesse 'response', os dados pode está armazenados dentro dele

Comment: Qual banco de dados que você está puxando os dados para o seu banco?

Comment: Eu puxo os dados do Oracle, mas acredito que consegui resolver aqui cara, muito obrigado pela atenção!!! Abraço.

Comment: @MatheusLima você pode postar a resposta para sua pergunta, ela pode ajudar outras pessoas.